# Compressing a string using GZIPOutputStream

Tags: android, string, compression, gzip, gzipoutputstream

I want to zip my string values. These string values should be same as `.net` zipped strings.

I wrote *Decompress* method and when I send a `.net` zipped string to it, it works correctly. But the *Compress* method does not work correctly.

```java
public static String Decompress(String zipText) throws IOException {
    int size = 0;
    byte[] gzipBuff = Base64.decode(zipText);

    ByteArrayInputStream memstream = new ByteArrayInputStream(gzipBuff, 4,
            gzipBuff.length - 4);
    GZIPInputStream gzin = new GZIPInputStream(memstream);

    final int buffSize = 8192;
    byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[buffSize];
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    while ((size = gzin.read(tempBuffer, 0, buffSize)) != -1) {
        baos.write(tempBuffer, 0, size);
    }
    byte[] buffer = baos.toByteArray();
    baos.close();

    return new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
}
```

```java
public static String Compress(String text) throws IOException {
    byte[] gzipBuff = EncodingUtils.getBytes(text, "UTF-8");

    ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    GZIPOutputStream gzin = new GZIPOutputStream(bs);

    gzin.write(gzipBuff);
    gzin.finish();
    bs.close();

    byte[] buffer = bs.toByteArray();
    gzin.close();

    return Base64.encode(buffer);
}
```

For example when I send **"BQAAAB+LCAAAAAAABADtvQdgHEmWJSYvbcp7f0r1StfgdKEIgGATJNiQQBDswYjN5pLsHWlHIymrKoHKZVZlXWYWQMztnbz33nvvvffee++997o7nU4n99//P1xmZAFs9s5K2smeIYCqyB8/fnwfPyLmeVlW/w+GphA2BQAAAA=="** to *Decompress* method It returns the string "Hello", but when I send **"Hello"** to *Compress* method It returns **"H4sIAAAAAAAAAMtIzcnJBwCGphA2BQAAAA=="**.

What is the problem in *Compress* method????

Answer (score 3):

Check [Use Zip Stream and Base64 Encoder to Compress Large String Data](http://lifelongprogrammer.blogspot.com/2013/11/java-use-zip-stream-and-base64-to-compress-big-string.html)

about how to use GZIPOutputStream/GZIInputStream and Base64 Encoder and Decoder to compress and uncompress large string data, so it can be passed as text in http response.

```
public static String compressString(String srcTxt) throws IOException {
  ByteArrayOutputStream rstBao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  GZIPOutputStream zos = new GZIPOutputStream(rstBao);
  zos.write(srcTxt.getBytes());
  IOUtils.closeQuietly(zos);

  byte[] bytes = rstBao.toByteArray();
  return Base64.encodeBase64String(bytes);
}
```

Or we can use [Use Zip Stream and Base64 Encoder to Compress Large String Data](http://lifelongprogrammer.blogspot.com/2013/11/java-use-zip-stream-and-base64-to-compress-big-string.html) to avoid load whole string into memory.

```
public static String uncompressString(String zippedBase64Str) throws IOException {
  String result = null;
  byte[] bytes = Base64.decodeBase64(zippedBase64Str);
  GZIPInputStream zi = null;
  try {
    zi = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
    result = IOUtils.toString(zi);
  } finally {
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(zi);
  }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Please, try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers, to get more understanding how to **not** answer. Namely: "Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question": **barely more than a link to an external site**

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with java vm i suppose the result is the same.
Use this line at the end of your Compress method :

```
return new String(base64.encode(buffer), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: sorry in android The constructor String(String, String) is undefined

Comment: the documentation talk about encodeToString() method : [Base64.html](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html#encode%28byte[],%20int%29). I cannot try it i cannot install android on my PC.