# Convert a String into a byte[] array keeping the same values

Tags: java, string, byte, encode

I'm working on a project in Java.
I used cipher to encode and decode.
Cipher returns me a byte array.
For some reasons I have to send this byte array in String
Do you have any ideas on how can I get back the same byte array?

For example, if I had the String:

```
"[B@5024d44"
```

and I want to convert into `byte[]` but I want the `byte[]` to be equals to `[B@5024d44`. Is it possible?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

`[B@5024d44` tells you you have a byte array, and tells you **nothing whatsoever** about what is in it.  You *cannot* convert that back to anything meaningful.

To convert a byte array to a `String` reversibly, use [`Base64`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string `[B@5024d44`, you can convert it to a `byte[]` array, and then convert this array back to a string. These two strings would be equal, but the array wouldn't be equal to the string, and also the contents of the array wouldn't be equal to the string:

```java
String str = "[B@5024d44";
byte[] arr = str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
String str1 = new String(arr, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

// strings are equal
System.out.println(str.equals(str1)); // true

// string representation of the array
System.out.println(arr); // [B@5451c3a8

// contents of the array
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
// [91, 66, 64, 53, 48, 50, 52, 100, 52, 52]
```

---

<sup>See also: [How can I convert a string into a GZIP Base64 string?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66409602/15309136)</sup>